# "The guideline" and "the rule"?

Tags: word-usage

How do you explain what kind of guideline a person has to follow?

Should I say "the guideline/rule ***is that***" like the examples below?

> "The guideline you need to follow on this assignment ***is that*** you should do a thorough research."
>
> "The guideline I have been following ***is that*** I do a thorough research."
>
> "The rule you need to follow ***is that*** you should do a thorough research."

**Edit:**
Okay, maybe my question wasn't clear at all. What if I insist on explaining what kind of rule/guideline a student has to follow to a friend by using "the rule/guideline is that" construction? Is this construction not possible at all?

Should I say something like *"you need to follow the guideline/rule, which is that you should do a thorough research"?*

Comment: Such constructs are allowable, but they read rather wordily, I think. There are several ways you can convey the thought: with or without the _that_, with or without the rule in quotation marks, by using commas or colons, etc. [Here are a couple examples](http://books.google.com/books?id=9zMVAAAAYAAJ&pg=PA20&dq=%22the+rule+to+follow+is%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=-v9-UbWOFOPh4APV64DYCQ&ved=0CD4Q6AEwAw#v=onepage&q=%22the%20rule%20to%20follow%20is%22&f=false), but there's no single "best" way to do this.

Answer (score 2):

I would take out the *is* altogether:

> You should follow this rule: do thorough research!

Although I think it would be better to be even more direct, and not even mention rules or guidelines at all:

> **You need to do thorough research.**

---

In general, when I proofread my own writing, and I noticed that I've used the *is* construct like you have:

> *The reason I'm saying this is because you don't want to be too wordy*.

I usually end up striking most of the first part altogether; it's superfluous:

> *Don't be too wordy*.

Answer (score 1):

It seems to me that you have two choices given the ambiguity of your three example sentences.

The first choice is to use the this sentence:

> The rule you **must follow** is this: Do a thorough job of research.

Rules aren't guidelines. Rules are directions that must be obeyed for fear of punishment if they are disobeyed; guidelines are mere suggestions. Well, that's one standard way of looking at the difference between these two words. You can also argue that **a guideline must be followed**, in which case you're using a weak metaphor for a strong statement.

The second choice is to use this sentence:

> The guideline you **should follow** is this: You **should do** as thorough a job of research as possible.

First decide what you want to say, then **say what you mean and mean what you say**.